# Trying to iterate through the nodes of a multipolygon

Tags: python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, nodes

I've got a multipolygon which I want to iterate through the nodes for. I will be editing the nodes later on, but right now I just want some code which works.

My relevant code is just this bit:

```
for featureW in layerWorking.getFeatures():
if featureW['SW_MEMBER'] == My_SW_MEMBER:
    print('Found <<TARGET>> feature')
```

So I've found the feature I want to target, and want to iterate through the nodes in a loop to, say, get their coordinates.

It should be noted that, whilst the layer TYPE is multipolygon (as there are a handful there), the shapes I'll be looking at are just individual polygons. I'm also using QGIS 3.4.5

Comment: you absolutely want to achieve this programmatically ? Wouldn't you try the **"extract vertices"** treatment of the processing toolbox ?

Comment: Could do. I've got to get this back into a polygon (or multipolygon, though none of the shapes are multipolygons) at the end.

Comment: Didnt my answer work?

Comment: Sorry, got tasked onto a different project. I can't remember how I did this one.

Answer (score 2):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    print('Processing feature {0}'.format(feature.id()))
    geom = feature.geometry()
    for part in geom.parts():
        for p in part.vertices():
            print(p)
```

[image]